# How to show full outline for interlocking circles without sending to the background

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am trying to do a venn diagram in visio and have dragged three interlocking circles onto a blank page.  Problem is that the inner lines disappear where they overlap - I have tried playing around with the formatting but cannot show the circles in their entirety where they overlap.  Help please :-(

Answer (score 3):

Edit properties of the shape, solid fill, adjust transparency to the desired level.

This is an image I got with that:

[image]